# Plotting multiple files every file in separate graph using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, multiple-file-upload

I have more than 1000 files named as "snap%d_beta800.dat" where %d is a number between 1 and 1000. 
I want to plot every one of these files in a separate surface plot (splot function) (using three columns) , save the result in png format with the same name as the original file: e.g snap1.png
I want to write a script that can do this for all the 1000 files in just once by loading a gpl file 
In addition to that  i want to create an animation for the 1000 files. 
I am appreciating if you can help with that and please have a look of what I tried 
what I tried does not give me a separate plot for every file, it just accumulates the plots of all the files in only one plot

```
set term png

splot [][][-3:3] for [i=1:1000] 'snap'.i.'_beta800.dat' us\

($1)-($4)/2:($2)-($5)/2:($3*0)-($6)/2:\
($4)*1:($5)*1:($6):($6) w vec head filled size screen 0.015,10,30 lw 2 lc pal z 

set output "snap".i.".png"

replot

set term x11
```

Comment: You could create a `do for` loop. Inside it you could define a `filename` variable using the iterator, concatenate it to create the `input` and `output` filenames, and then pass `input` to `splot` command.

Answer (score 1):

As @GRSousaJr wrote, put it into a `do for` loop.
I'm wondering why you are writing your plot command like this:

```
... using ($1)-($4)/2:($2)-($5)/2:($3*0)-($6)/2:($4)*1:($5)*1:($6):($6) ...
```

I would simply write:

```
... using ($1-$4/2):($2-$5/2):(-$6/2):4:5:6:6 ...
```

**Code:**

```
### Batch create PNG files
set term pngcairo size 600,600

do for [i=1:1000] {
    fname_in = sprintf("snap%d_beta800.dat",i)
    fname_out = sprintf("snap%d_beta800.png",i)
    set output fname_out
    splot fname_in u ($1-$4/2):($2-$5/2):(-$6/2):4:5:6:6 \
        w vec head filled size screen 0.015,10,30 lw 2 lc pal z
}
set output
### end of code
```

I assume you want create your animation from these 1000 PNG files with some other software. Maybe you are aware that you can also create an animated GIF with gnuplot:

**Code:**

```
### Create animated file
set term gif size 600,600 animate delay 12 loop 0 optimize
set output "Animation.gif"
do for [i=1:1000] {
    fname = sprintf("snap%d_beta800.dat",i)
    splot fname u ($1-$4/2):($2-$5/2):(-$6/2):4:5:6:6 \
        w vec head filled size screen 0.015,10,30 lw 2 lc pal z
}
set output
### end of code
```